How do I fix this error when try to update via terminal?
I'm new to Linux and Terminals so any "obvious answers" may not appeal to me as easily.
When trying to update via `sudo apt update` I am thrown the following errors.

"The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu jammy Release"
"Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default."
"See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details."
Does anybody body have a super simple fix? Even if it's not simple, please just explain it step by step.
Thanks in advance!

The latest deb file at that location is for disco (very old), so you might be better off getting the compressed tar and trying to build it yourself. If not really needed, you can remove the repository, so you won't see the error.

Try sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oguzhaninan/stacer --remove
